# Why is my cats top fur matted?

Tags: cats, health, grooming

What causes my cats matted fur? I think its sap from the bushes she crawls into. Others say long haired cats get knots when they shed.

Comment: Welcome to Pet Exchange, what breed is your cat?

Answer (score 2):

All cats shed, and even short haired cats can get mats when they shed; long haired cats are even more prone to it. The best way to prevent that is by regular grooming. (Some cats will self-groom efficiently enough, but may develop hairball problems). Try brushing once or twice a week to see if that helps. If sap is causing the problem, I would expect it to be sticky. If the mats seem to be dry and not brittle, then shedding is most likely the problem.